# Where can I see the list of review audits I failed?

Tags: support, review-audits

I had failed review audits in the past and was banned from reviewing for a while. While I was banned, I was able to see the list of every audit I failed (it was at the tab where the review queues are). But now that the ban is lifted, I can't find that list anymore. Where can I find it?

Comment: Inside a review queue there should be a *Stats* and *History* tab. Are the failed audits not in there?

Comment: @vandench no it's not there; it has what actions I've taken, not how I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

A moderator can dig them up (or at least the last 15) for you by going to `https://stackoverflow.com/admin/review/suspensions/suspend-user?userId=YOUR-USER-ID-HERE` and selecting "Failed audits" from the dropdown on that page.  I think we'd respond favorably to requests by users for the list so that they can improve, though the flag response message length limit of 200 chars really limits what we can put in it.  Meta comments, of course, allow for much more text.

You might be able to get the list of incorrect review that resulted in your review suspension, which if manual will differ from the failed audits, by going through your [inbox history](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).  I haven't tested this, though, since I don't have a sock with review privileges, though.  Someone should let me know in the comments if it does or does not work.

Comment: Related (old) FR on MSE [I would like to see my review audit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209324/1099857)

Comment: If you have my userscript installed, it adds a "See all failed audits" button on  https://stackoverflow.com/users/history/17521785?type=User+has+been+suspended+from+reviewing

Comment: @SamuelLiew that only retrieves the last 30 days' worth (in this case, none), which is unlikely to be more than 15: I don't think it's possible to fail 15 audits in 30 days.

Comment: Ah I see. Maybe I should make the button link directly to this new page then https://stackoverflow.com/admin/review/recent-reviews-for-user-table?userId=17521785&task=failed-audits